# Is “You can only post once every 20 minutes.” applied for multiple site?

Tags: support, asking-questions

There is a strange problem happening to me. When I want to ask a question, a message saying “You can only post once every 20 minutes.” shows up. As far as I remember, what I did in the last 20 minutes is flag my own question due to low rating in stackoverflow.com.

Is this 20 minutes penalty applied across all Stack Exchange sites? That is, when you have asked a question in Stack Overflow you cannot ask in Ask Ubuntu for the next 20 minutes? And is the penalty applied not only for questions but also for flags and answers?

Answer (score 1):

The same rate limiting is applied per-site, for posting both questions and answers.

Comment: Why is this status completed? We're all still stuck on the same spam blocked IP..

Comment: if it is per site why I cannot ask a question in askubuntu.com within 20 minutes after i asked in stackoverflow.com ? is this because of ip ?

Comment: @whale_steward you've accessed the site from an ip that was flagged as origin of network-wide spam at one point, as Seth already noted

Comment: @whale_steward Try again, SE has fixed their issues and your IP looks clean now.